# EXIM on Cpanel - system user spam?

Tags: exim

In the `exim_mainlo`, the following user is sending unsolicited emails:

> from email@domain.com U=user223 P=local S=1274
>   id=96ffd95a9fc530b5553270b6b3e6f107@domain.com T="spam subject was
>   here"

Is the `U=user223` the system user?

Answer (score 0):

`U=user223` is the user retrieved from the remote server using the `ident` service.  These days so few servers support `ident` calls that I have disable the call in my configuration.  It appears this is enabled in your configuration.

Based on the remote user, I suspect this may be a Spam message of some sort.  However, this is only one of a number of factors I use.